# MDX formula avg for last 35 days

Tags: excel, mdx

How can I average a Measure from my olap table by creating an MDX formula thru Excel's Set Manger (new set via MDX) or using Olap PivotTable extensions.

What I need is to get the average of a measurer called [Rental Count] for the last 35 days.  my date dimension is [Rental Date].[Date] I also have a dimension called location, so I want to be able to look this up by location.  some locations my have data for all 35 days, while others may have data for some of the 35 previous days.

Comment: which version of Excel are you using? - there is more `olap` functionality in 2013.

Comment: did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is straight `mdx` for a 35 day average:

```
AVG(
    TAIL(
      [Rental Date].[Date].[Date]
     ,35
    ) 
   ,[Measures].[Rental Count]   
)
```

`Excel-2013` has custom measures built in.

An alternative is a more generic solution for any measure. so in the following we could put this on columns, and then have various measures on rows (as long as this is created as a member of a hierarchy **other** than measures)

```
AVG(
    TAIL(
      [Rental Date].[Date].[Date]
     ,35
    ) 
)
```

If you want this average to consider more than just the last 35 days in the date dimension and you will be including date on say Rows, then something similar to this is good:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[MovingAvg35Days] AS 
    Avg
    (
      [Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember.Lag(35) : [Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember
     ,[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
    ) 
SELECT 
  {
    [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
   ,[Measures].[Internet Order Count]
   ,[Measures].[MovingAvg35Days]
  } ON 0
 ,Descendants
  (
    [Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Year].&[2007]
   ,[Date].[Calendar].[Date]
  ) ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

Comment: thank you for answer, I get an error that says " the function expects a tuple set expression for the argument. a string or numeric expression was used.

Comment: I had to guess the second `[Date]` so maybe in your cube you need to use `[Rental Date].[Date]` rather than `[Rental Date].[Date].[Date]` .... which one returns the set of all dates in your cube?

Comment: Thank you for your continued help in this.  I keep getting an error that says "the function expects a tuple set expression for the argument.  a string or numeric was used.  if I just use the Tail([Rental Date].[Date],35) then I do get the last 35 day's of detail data.(that's how I'm getting the data currently.  I use cubevalue function to retrieve the daily detail & then just get the avg in excel)  just can't seem to get the AVG for some reason. was hoping to just be able to get the avg in one column, without having all the daily data.

Comment: @Enayat try creating a custom set in Excel called "Last35Days" using the mdx `Tail([Rental Date].[Date],35)` then create a custom measure using the expression `AVG(Last35Days,[Measures].[Rental Count] )` ... you should see the set Last35Days that you have just created in the list of hierarchies. I will try prototyping this against AdvWrks and will add some screen-prints tomorrow.

Comment: whytheq THANK YOU! so much for making the time to answer help in solving this problem for me.

Comment: I tried your last suggestion & am still getting the error. the function expects a tuple set expression for the argument. a string or numeric expression was used.  I'm just wondering if I'm not articulating the issue clearly enough?   in the mean time I did find another way to solve my immediate needs. I was able to use a cubeset formula to create the date range. then use a cubevalue formula to refrence the date range & retrieve the avg 35 days of values. Cubeset("my data","[Rental Date].[Date].&[cell reference for 1st date] : [Rental Date].[Date].&[cell reference for 2nd date range]")